# How can I sync two JTable and JTableHeader when column moved?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have two JTable and they have to sync of all means each other.
These two JTable are set recording allowed.

So I want to know how to sync JTableHeader behavior when columns moved.

thanks a lot, dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that purposes you can use `TableColumnModelListener` which has [`columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent arg0)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableColumnModelListener.html#columnMoved%28javax.swing.event.TableColumnModelEvent%29). That allow you to swap columns in other table according source table. Example code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableColumnModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableColumnModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }

    public Example() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rotation");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTable t = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{{1,2}},new Object[]{"1","2"}));
        final JTable t1 = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{{1,2}},new Object[]{"1","2"}));

        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(t),BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(t1),BorderLayout.EAST);

        t.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(new TableColumnModelListener() {

            @Override
            public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void columnRemoved(TableColumnModelEvent arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent arg0) {
                int fromIndex = arg0.getFromIndex();
                int toIndex = arg0.getToIndex();
                t1.moveColumn(fromIndex, toIndex);
            }

            @Override
            public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void columnAdded(TableColumnModelEvent arg0) {
            }
        });

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: hi alex2410: it works!thanks a lot dude. but one defect is these two tables cannot sync each other, 'cause the front table trigger 'moveColumn' of the other, and method 'moveColumn' will trigger another event. thought it will be an infinite loop.

Comment: hi Alex2410: 
sorry but i don't understand what u mean.
i don't know how to set flag when the event triggers.
thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

my code is as below

```
 public static void syncTableColumnOrder(final JTable main, final JTable... tables) {

    /* if table is not reordering-allowed, this method is meaningless */
    if (!main.getReorderingAllowed()) 
        return;

    /* if two tables trigger event each other, it'll be infinite loop */
    for (JTable table : tables) {
        if (table == null) continue;
        table.setReorderingAllowed(false);
    }

    /* when main table moves coloumn, effect others */
    main.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(new TableColumnModelListener() {
        @Override
        public void columnAdded(TableColumnModelEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void columnRemoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
            for (JTable table : tables) {
                table.moveColumn(e.getFromIndex(), e.getToIndex());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {}
    });
}
```